# Enable Publish/Unpublish in Child Publications Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing

how to enable (Also Publish/Unpublish in Child Publications) option automatically checked using Tridion 2013 SP1 -HR1

[image: publishing]

Comment: Can we implement  a plugin similar  to http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/55a2e902e4de020cc484cc6c please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of box feature which will help enable automatic selection of the checkbox. You will have to write a GUI extension for the same which is the right way to go about it for implementing this kind of functionality. For details on how to write a GUI extension, you can refer the following links:

[TridionWorld GUI Example](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/GUIextensionIn8steps.aspx): this one is really helpful in terms of an example to understand extensions and how they work
[SDL Official Documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-44562CE1-5D81-4E64-B65B-C8BFA0BAA53D&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-44562CE1-5D81-4E64-B65B-C8BFA0BAA53D.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-44562CE1-5D81-4E64-B65B-C8BFA0BAA53D&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dgui%2520extension&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1459579937218&currentQuery=gui%2520extension&currentScope=)

Answer (score 0):

As Vipin says, you can write a GUI extension to do this, but with this kind of thing, requirements are everything. What do you want to achieve? If it's simply about checking the checkbox, then use a GUI extension. If you want to change the semantics of publishing so that child publications are always published, then you can enforce this by writing an event handler. In that case, you may still wish to write a GUI extension so that you don't have a misleading checkbox.

Comment: Thanks vipin and dominic. I would like the enable the check box so the content editor knows the page or components  will be published to child publications at the same time it should publish the page or component to child publication too. It works fine on tridion 2009 but not on tridion 2013 sp1. Will explore  the gui extension example to implement  a plugin similar  to http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/55a2e902e4de020cc484cc6c . Tridion 2013 sp1. Thanks to the answers.