# Publishing: set per default "Also Publish/Unpublish in Child Publications"

Tags: publishing, gui-extensions

Editors always forget to set "Also Publish/Unpublish in Child Publications" when they publish specific Pages from a specific Publication. The question would be:

Is it possible to check per default the checkbox "Also Publish/Unpublish in Child Publications" for a specific Publication?

As from what I read here it is not possible:
[Enable Publish/Unpublish in Child Publications Tridion 2013 SP1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14309/enable-publish-unpublish-in-child-publications-tridion-2013-sp1)

Is it maybe now somehow possible within Web 8.5 or with a specific plugin or whatever? Is some Extension out there? (Web 8.1 / Web 8.5)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question is something you could have easily found in the release notes of SDL Web 8 and 8.5: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-FE5B8181-1EF3-4821-A025-1E01598340A4 and https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-10A67F1F-D1D5-48CA-B74E-132812011BB4

This tells you there is still no out of box feature which will help enable automatic selection of the checkbox. As a solution you can still write a GUI extension yourself implementing this.

Additionally you can also submit an idea on our community site, requesting for that functionality in a future release: https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas

Comment: Did the request in parallel: https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/publishing-set-per-default-also-publish-to-child-publication-per-publication?Redirected=true

Comment: Only thought there is already code for such a GUI extension to support our developers.

Comment: I posted an answer below with some code incase it still helps @SteffenDrotschmann

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a bit late to the party, but I've written a short extension and blog post on how to do exactly what you're after as I had a similar requirement recently.

You can read my quick blog post which outlines how to set the advanced published setting as the default here:

- https://www.whobrokethebuild.me/default-publish-settings-in-sdl-tridion/